# SAS Enterprise - Is it possible to show the mathematical formula behind the calculation?

Tags: sas

is it possible to show the mathemetical formular / concept behind the analysis done with SAS Enterprise?

Assuming SAS would calculate a correlation between a list of numbers -- is it possible to see what exactly SAS did from a mathematical perspective?

Comment: Check the documentation. They include formulas for most statistical methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to ask SAS for the mathematical formula, no.  You can check the documentation; for example, [this page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473330.htm) gives many of the 'elemantary statistics' formulas (like variance, UCLM, etc.)

If you need the formula behind something more complex that you can't find online, contact your SAS Support rep, and they may be able to put you in contact with the developer of that particular proc - like if you need to know some particular to how `PROC GLM` does something.

You can ask SAS to give you the SAS code that it ran if you executed a task (in most cases it's available by clicking on the task node), in many cases,  but that would be something like `proc freq; tables a*b; run;`, not a mathematical formula per se.